# Quarkus service passing parameter other than String type results in error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, quarkus

I am developing an application using Vuejs which calls the Java service. This service is will take a parameter. If I pass the parameter as `String` then it would accept and continue with execution. However, this input corresponds to my `Java Object Model` type hence if I change the type to my `Java Object` type then I get the error:

`Unable to obtain data, Error: Error: Request failed with status code 500`

I would like to change the InputParameter type to my custom Java type can someone please tell me what I need to do for this?

Following is the working code with `String type`:

```
@POST
@Path("/generate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "returns list of JSON Objects"),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal Server Error occurred")
})
public String generate(final String inputParameter){
    System.out.println(inputTemplate);
    return null;
}
```

The above code works fine and I am able to get the `inputParameter` printed, But I know that my `inputParameter` will always be my Custom java object type `InputParameter` so if I change the type then the execution won't detect the method and nothing is being printed and I get the error `POST http://localhost:9001/generateTestData 500 (Internal Server Error)`:

```
@POST
@Path("/generate")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "returns list of JSON Objects"),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal Server Error occurred")
})
public String generate(final InputParameter inputParameter){
    System.out.println(inputTemplate.toString());
    return null;
}
```

Following is the call I am making in my `vuejs` application:

```
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

this.$axios.post('/generate', { ...JSON.parse(inputParameter) }, { headers })
.then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: What does the stacktrace show? I'm guessing that the body is null and when you do `inputTemplate.toString()`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown

Comment: @MatheusCirillo Actually its not showing anything maybe because it's not detecting that method at all as the `inputparameter` is not of String type. But my browser console shows the message `xhr.js:187          POST http://localhost:9001/generate 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?